# Instancing tuple and non-tuple under the same class

Tags: haskell, tuples, typeclass, functor

I am trying to implement an `Unzippable` class for unzipping *n*-tuples nested in *m* functors.

This implementation behaves fine:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, FlexibleContexts #-}

class Unzippable tp where
  unzip   :: (Functor f)
             => f tp -> Unzipped f tp
  unzip'  :: (Functor f, Functor g, Unzippable (Unzipped g tp))
             => f (g tp) -> Unzipped f (Unzipped g tp)
  {- unzip'' etc... -}
  -----------------------------------
  unzip' x = unzip (unzip <$> s)
  {- implicit implementation for unzip'' etc... -}


type family Unzipped (f :: * -> *) tp where
  Unzipped f (a1, a2)      = (f a1, f a2)
  Unzipped f (a1, a2, a3)  = (f a1, f a2, f a3)
  {- ... -}

instance Unzippable (a1, a2) where
  unzip x = (fst <$> x, snd <$> x)

instance Unzippable (a1, a2, a3) where
  unzip x = ((\(a,_,_) -> a) <$> x, 
             (\(_,a,_) -> a) <$> x, 
             (\(_,_,a) -> a) <$> x)
```

Testing it does what it should:

```
λ> let x = [(1,2,3),(1,2,3)]
λ> let y = [x,x,x]
λ> unzip' y
([[1,1],[1,1],[1,1]],[[2,2],[2,2],[2,2]],[[3,3],[3,3],[3,3]])
```

My question: is it possible to implement an instance for non-tupled types for the class `Unzippable`? I am trying to hide the *possible* unzipping for some generic higher-order function interfaces, through a single function (in my case a postfix operator, e.g. `(-<) = unzip'`).

The following attempt:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, FlexibleContexts, FlexibleInstances #-}

type family Unzipped (f :: * -> *) tp where
  {- ... -}
  Unzipped f a1 = f a1

instance Unzippable a1 where
  unzip x = x
```

gives the error:

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘Unzipped f a1’
              with actual type ‘f a1’
• In the expression: x
  In an equation for ‘unzip’: unzip x = x
  In the instance declaration for ‘Unzippable a1’
• Relevant bindings include
    x :: f a1 
    unzip :: f a1 -> Unzipped f a1
```

Comment: If you try to make an `instance Unzippable a1` you'll quickly get into overlapping instances territory which you are best off avoiding. Try making an instance for [`Identity`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.1.0/docs/Data-Functor-Identity.html) instead.

Comment: @Cirdec right, are you saying that I should make `instance Unzippable (Identity a1)` with the implementation `unzip x = runIdentity <$> x`? In this case it seems to be working since, as you said, it does not overlap with the previous instances. Or is there another solution without the need to map `Identity` over the input?

Comment: Yes, I think Cirdec is saying that. It's generally unwise to try to define instances for "not X", since those will overlap and behave a bit badly. If there are really only finitely many zippable types and you can describe them all in one place, you can make this work reasonably well with either overlapping instances or type family tricks, but "open world" overlapping is generally awful.

Comment: Thank you for clearing this out for me! I guess `Identity` works as well as any other constructor available (and I have a few in my sleeve which work nicely to hide the unzipping). If you'd like to write your feedback as an answer I would gratefully accept it.